# Require JS Object and Functions in Typescript Angular2 project

Tags: javascript, typescript, require

I am working with **Typescript** **2**.1.5 and trying to write some newer sections of code with it. 
I have a **JS** *library* that i am not ready to update in Typescript. The problem is that **i need to consume some of that Javascript code** in a simple Typescript component.

I have been fetching the web for a way to get my Javascript functions to get called and work in a .TS file. Unfortunatly informations are either ***outdated***(mostly), **not clear** or not explained at all. I allready tryed a whole lot of tricks but none works.

So my question is : What is the **easiest** way and **simplest way** to consume javascript code in a TS file (ES6) ? There must be a protocol to follow to get this done.

Any tutorial, link or explanations will be much appreciated and i'am sure will help others in the same situation.

For better understanding here are some code snippets :

*I start by doing an import of my JS file in the component.ts*

```
var ZP = require('./zp.js');
```

*In my js file i have two types of functions. Respectively a basic one and another which are methods from an object:*

```
**export** function logTest(){
    console.log("Responding");
}//Simple function
```

(***i just found while editing, that by appending the keyword "export" to the simple function makes it avaible to call in TS file. Wich doesn't work with methods ***).

```
DObject.stringtest = function(){
    return "Responding";
} //Object Method
```

Back to my **component.ts** file i call each one. The **simple function** with the **export keyword** now gets called, but the **DObject** ***method*** remains undefined. 
(I made dummy calls for the **DObject** just to show what doesn't work even if it can seem obvious to some).

```
testFunc(event){
      console.log("event is okay");
      console.log(ZP.logTest()); <--- Now Works
      console.log(ZP.stringTest()); <--- Don't Work
      console.log(ZP.DObject.stringTest()); <--- Don't Work
      console.log(ZP.DObject.stringTest); <--- Don't Work
      }
```

Here are the console logs :

```
DObject.stringTest is not a function
```

( For the first two calls to stringTest() )

```
Undefined
```

( For the last call to DObject.stringTest )

*( I just found something about Declaration files, i ll give it a shot, hopefully if it works i ll edit a full explained step by step tutorial. In the mean time any help would be much appreciated. )*

Comment: Just import it. All JS are valid TS

Comment: I heard that but when i query a function from the JS file i got an error : xxx is not a function. Plus it is not possible to super in the constructor to use it as in the this context.

Comment: Try to post some sample code to help explain your problem.  What is a simple function in your JavaScript file ? How are you trying to use it in TypeScript ? How are you importing this file ? Basic information like this will help others to diagnose your problem correctly.

Answer (score -1):

In your case your existing javascript files are not detected in typescript because typings are not available.

you can create a type definition (index.d.ts) file and keep adding your typings so that it will be available to your tsc compiler.

Below are few thing you need to understand when coming to the typescript world. Some of you might know, some may not.

- every typescript file transpiled to java script into specific version you want in tsconfig.json
- typescript understand typescript ( for javascript type definition is required) or type definition.
- there are many typing available in 2 forms :

  1. typings install
  2. @types namespace package
- import and export makes available your members and properties to others

Comment: Okay, but how is the structure of a Object declaration in the .d.ts file ? How the compiler knows that my DObject exist ? How can i declare fairly static functions(method) like DObject.Counter = function(){...} ? Then how to call them ? Is the require variable name is enough ? do i have to import the .d.ts file ?